# Android Error testing app using Mock Location

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, gps

I'm trying to test my Android location based app.

It would be very useful if I could mock location data from providers in unit tests. But I can't add `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` permission to `androidManifest.xml` because when I do so it gives me an error:

> Mock locations should only be requested in a debug-specific manifest file (typically src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml)
>   Using a mock location provider (by requiring the permission
>   android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION) should only be done in debug
>   builds. In Gradle projects, that means you should only request this
>   permission in a debug source set specific manifest file.  To fix this,
>   create a new manifest file in the debug folder and move the
>    element there. A typical path to a debug manifest
>   override file in a Gradle project is src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.

But I when add `AndroidManifest.xml` to `src/androidTest` directory - it just ignores it when testing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggests, i.e. using `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: of course I did - still ignoring my AndroidManifest.xml when running test cases, throwing exception: `java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting`

Comment: "*of course I did*" > Ok, just checking. Your question doesn't tell anyone that you tried that.

Comment: It's OK, I've stuck with this issue for weeks, and tried everything that came up to my mind. At the same time I found out that this kind of testing is called `integration testing` and one of the solutions is creating a separate test-project for that. But I could not make it work either. Though, it's not a very critical issue (I'm testing my app without mocking GPS and NETWORK providers, just creating my custom ones), it's a very interesting question for me, and I hope not only for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this problem and I think I figured out the solution.  Make sure that "Access mock locations" is checked in your device Developer Options (in addition to making an "src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml" file declaring usage of the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission, as you are already doing).

Comment: It seems weird to me, that I haven't tried to do it this way before, but I tried right now and it just worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> But I when add AndroidManifest.xml to src/androidTest directory - it just ignores it when testing.

Have you tried putting it in the src/debug folder according to the error message? That should work just fine.

Comment: of course I did - still ignoring my AndroidManifest.xml when running test cases, throwing exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting

Comment: and you're sure that you generate a debug build when trying to test it, and not a release build? I'd also make sure to double check the gradle files.

Comment: hmm... and could you please tell, how can I do it?